# How to find out what table's primary keys are using a select query

Tags: database, oracle, select, primary-key

Is it possible to run `SELECT PIRMARY_KEY FROM SomeTable`, where `PRIMARY_KEY` is a keyword that will automatically translate to SomeTable's primary key columns

I am using **Oracle** database

Comment: Do you mean something along the lines of `SELECT PIRMARY_KEY FROM SomeTable`, where `PRIMARY_KEY` is a keyword that will automatically translate to SomeTable's primary key columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select cc.column_name
from user_cons_columns cc
join user_constraints c on c.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
where c.table_name = 'MYTABLE'
and c.constraint_type = 'P'
order by cc.position
```

You can read more about these and other useful data dictionary views in the [Oracle Database Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/toc.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking "how do I figure out what the primary key is for any given table", then 'desc table_name' will show you all the details you need to know.

Comment: The question is along the lines of how to find it out with the help of select query?

Answer (score 0):

This is database specific.  The information usually resides in a proprietary system table.

Most of the time, however, the database implementation is nice enough to provide you with a stored procedure to fetch this information.  There are API's around that will provide you with database agnostic ways to get this information, but I suspect you are after something accessible directly from SQL.  Post your particular database type and I'm sure someone will know.

Comment: Michael - i am using Oracle database